# Version Control Software without Server setup

Tags: git, svn, version-control

So I've just joined this company which is launching it's e-Learning team. People here aren't exactly tech savy and aren't open to setting up new servers etc.
We currently use One Drive to share files & excel sheets to document bugs, issues etc.
Is there any Version Control Software we can use which doesn't require any complicated steps of setting up on servers?
We're a team of 6-7, where files including source code, would be shared and updated by each.

Comment: Open a repository on Github or Bitbucket or some other service.

Comment: I'd suggest GitHub https://github.com/

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest Bitbucket and VSTS (Visual Studio Team Services). The Github is free for public and open source repositories. But assuming you will need private repository which is paid on the Github. Bitbucket and VSTS provide unlimited private repositories for team size of upto 5 members. You will need to pay for each additional member above 5 members.

If you are looking for a solution to manage the documents other than source code files, like excel documents, then you can think of integrating 'xtrail' (https://www.xltrail.com) or similar solutions with your git repository.

As you mentioned the people on your team are not much tech savy, so you can also give a thought to the selection on type (distributed vs centralized) of version control system. The distributed systems like Git provides way better flexibility and out of the box workflows than centralized systems like SVN. But one might find it complex to understand the distributed workflows and concepts.